# Double Integration of a custom equation by fit() Matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, numerical-integration, differentiation

Is it possible to double integrate a function that is a result of a fit() (the type of function is cfit).

The differentiation is easy using the following function `differentiate(myfit,points);`

While Integration using `integrate(myfit,points,start);` results in the integral as a set of values at the points location. Is there a function in matlab that returns another function similar to differentiate()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
f = fit(xdata, ydata,'cubicinterp');
% function integration
I1 = fit(xdata, integrate(f,xdata,0),'cubicinterp');
% double integration
integrate(I1,xdata,0)
```

where `xdata` is the argument of the function `ydata`.

Comment: Can you explain your code? I have two set of data ydata and xdata that I use fit() to fit between them. What is Fsample, xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question. Now is it suitable?